# copiar registros de una tabla con llaves foraneas

Tags: sql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al hacer la insercion de la tabla ReprteEgresado y copiar los datos de la tabla reportes:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ReporteEgresado]
           ([Observacion_ReporteEgresado]
           ,[Sancion_ReporteEgresado]
           ,[Fecha_ReporteEgresado]
           ,[AlumnoEgresado_Curp_AlumnoEgresado]
           ,[Grado_ReporteEgresado]
           ,[Grupo_ReporteEgresado]) select * from Reporte
```

me tira este error:

> "La lista de selección para la instrucción INSERT contiene más
>   elementos que la lista de inserción. El número de valores SELECT debe
>   coincidir con el número de columnas INSERT."

Comment: El mensaje de error que te tira me parece sumamente claro y entendible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con hacer un `select * FROM Reporte`, estás trayendo 7 columnas y solo pones el INSERT en 6, el `Id_reporte` es el que está de más, tendrás que

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ReporteEgresado]
           ([Observacion_ReporteEgresado]
           ,[Sancion_ReporteEgresado]
           ,[Fecha_ReporteEgresado]
           ,[AlumnoEgresado_Curp_AlumnoEgresado]
           ,[Grado_ReporteEgresado]
           ,[Grupo_ReporteEgresado]) 
 select 
 Observacion_Reporte, Sancion_Reporte {...} from Reporte
```

Para eliminar el `id_reporte` de la consulta

Comment: ahora me tira este error: "La instrucción INSERT entró en conflicto con la restricción FOREIGN KEY "ReporteEgresado_AlumnoEgresado". El conflicto ocurrió en la base de datos "TELESECUNDARIA", tabla "dbo.AlumnoEgresado", columna "Curp_AlumnoEgresado"."

Comment: Al parecer estás tratando de meter ids que no existen en las tablas, es decir en el insert ingresas Curp_alumno = 23, pero en la tabla de AlumnoEgresado no hay ningún registro con ese primary key, ahí tendrías que pasar primero la tabla alumno a la nueva tabla AlumnoEgresado